# Class-validator schema с env конфигом

Tags: javascript, typescript, валидация, nestjs, this

Всем привет.Хочу задать вопрос:
могу ли я работать с class-validator и использовать env конфиг в его схеме?
Сейчас проблема следующая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто можем помочь советом или ответом?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не можете обращаться к классу из декораторов.
Для получения подобного поведения вам понадобится создать [кастомный декоратор](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators) и каким-то волшебным образом внедрить туда `ConfigService`, либо использовать `process.env`, что в обоих случаях по сути будет являться костылём. (Пометить кастомный декоратор как `@Injectable()` и засунуть в `providers`? Хм, звучит интересно...)

Так что, если вы хотите получить возможность инъекции зависимостей, то используйте кастомный ValidationPipe, но тогда все проверки надо будет писать вручную, благо у `class-validator` помимо декораторов есть их функциональные аналоги (именуются с маленькой буквы, вроде `isEmail` вместо `IsEmail`).

Но всё же, я бы на вашем месте просто захардкодил бы нужное значение в декоратор и не парился бы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.Я бы тоже так сделал но тим лид против))

Comment: Один из вариантов кода кстати был const configService = new ConfigService().Но это наверно неадкватно,да?

Comment: Вы всё-равно не сможете засунуть его  в декоратор

Comment: Ну у меня почему-то ошибку не выдаёт.